# InterfaceError from Dockerized Django to local MySql connection

Tags: mysql, django, docker

Trying to connect local MySQL database from docker Django, unfortunately getting interface error don't know what's wrong.
Host Machine Info: Macbook Pro M1
Mysql Database Version: Mysql 8

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  django:
    build: ./project
    volumes:
      - ./project:/project
    ports:
      - "8081:8000"
    restart: unless-stopped


  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./project/media:/usr/share/nginx/media
      - ./project/static:/usr/share/nginx/static
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**local_settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host.docker.internal', 
        'PORT': '33060',
    }
}
```

error traceback

[image]

Comment: Your docker compose seems to be missing the mysql container

Comment: @Yogesh_D trying to connect localhost MySQL that's why the docker container is missing for MySQL.

Comment: post output of `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN"` on the host

Comment: kindly look at this URL I posted a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/QlKfelU the output of ```netstat -an | grep "LISTEN"``` command

Comment: As I would have guessed, your mysql is configured to listen on the loopback address (127.0.0.1) where as you are rightly using `host.docker.internal` to connect to mysql on the host.You need to change the bind address to 0.0.0.0 for mysql. Look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address. Depending on how you have installed mysql you should be able to find the config files and change this.

Comment: @Raijul Kashem any luck?